# MYSQL: REGEXP single quotation matching

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, quotes

I am having a trouble matching a string in a MySQL-query with the following regex:

I want it to match to this string: "Rue de l' Harmonie"

```
SELECT
  id,
  street_name
FROM
  street_names
WHERE
  street_name REGEXP '^(rue[a-z]+[[:blank:]])((du|de|la|des|d[\']|l[\'])[[:blank:]])*[[:<:]]HARMONIE$'
```

Anybody can give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning:

```
^(rue[a-z]+
```

The `+` requires that there be at least one a-z char directly following **rue**.  You probably want `*`.